# Smaller Album artwork in iTunes 12.5.1.21?

Tags: itunes, album-art

I have hundreds of different albums in my iTunes library and would like to see as many of them as I can while still remaining in windowed mode. Unfortunately, iTunes does not have a clear option to display albums in a smaller format.

I have gone under Preferences and selected "List View" as Smallest and I have also tried using <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> to select View Options but neither has had any impact.

How can I make these unnecessarily large album cover icons smaller so that I don't have to scroll through the equivalent of several pages to see my entire library?

[image: Album Covers are way too large!!!]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anyway you can make them smaller.  The Grid view, in Album View, I think is inoperable to size change.  For me, I like larger album covers so I deleted the microphones in Artist view (and Artist view itself) and use List in the Album View.  Of course, I can expand to about 14" x 14".  The only smaller album coverwork are the microphones but they seem to be controlled by the iTunes Store box sets, so many people have missing artwork---and lots of microphones.  That's why I eliminated them.